# Animate addtosubview for multiple subviews

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I am having an array of UIViews and I want to arrange them in a main view in a grid form, and I also wanted it to animate ( ie the grids should appear one by one slowly). Tried animating with in a for loop but didnt work but came up with a work around to achieve something closer to what I want, but just wanted to know if there is a better way to do this. I know there is some property with CAAnimationGroup (begintime) but sure how to connect it to addtosubview. Here is my code, let me know if there is a better way to do it.

```
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGFloat x = 0;
    CGFloat delay = .3;

    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 50, 50)];
        myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        myView.alpha = 0.0;
        x = x + 50+ 2;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [self.view addSubview:myView];
            myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
           // myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
                myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                myView.alpha = 1.0;
            }];

        }];
        delay = delay + .3;
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

-anoop

Comment: How didn't it work inside a loop? Did you try putting the loop INSIDE the animation block, instead of wrapping it? This way you are not creating multiple single animations, but one slightly more complex one.

Comment: If I try to put the entire loop in an animation block I wont get the one by one appearing anim effect, everthing displays at one shot. If you run my code, you would know what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Updated the code to add smooth animation, since I couldnt find a better way, I am going ahead with this approach. I shall wait for 1-2 days and will mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,I have also used animation within for loop but it didn't work
>   properly then I call a method that animate the view , multiple times
>   and it worked properly.I think this is better way to simply apply
>   animation. by calling a method.I m putting some code here may it will
>   help u.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    radius=82.097;
    rotationMultiplier=1;
    toAngle = fromAngle = 0;
    toStart = NO;
    center=CGPointMake(161, 233);

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click" ofType:@"mp3"];

    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];

    SingleTouchGesture *wheelRecogniser=[[SingleTouchGesture alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateWheel:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:wheelRecogniser];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(void) rotate:(int) time
{
    CABasicAnimation *topAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    topAnimation.duration=time;
    topAnimation.fromValue= [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fromAngle];
    topAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:toAngle];
    topAnimation.delegate = self;
    topAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    topAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [wheelImage.layer addAnimation:topAnimation forKey:@"transform"];
    fromAngle = toAngle;
}


-(void) rotateWheel:(SingleTouchGesture*) recogniser
{
    toAngle += recogniser.rotation;

    if (toStart) 
    {
        if (recogniser.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {
            NSLog(@"Speed === %f",recogniser.speed);
            rotationMultiplier=[self getMultiplier:recogniser.speed];
            NSLog(@"Rotation Multiplier..%f",rotationMultiplier);
            toStart = NO;   
            NSLog(@"State Ended");
            self.player.currentTime=0;
            [self.player play];

            if (recogniser.rotation>=0)
            {
                toAngle =fromAngle+(rotationMultiplier*3.14);
            }
            else
            {
                toAngle =fromAngle-(rotationMultiplier*3.14);
            }
        }

        [self rotate:1];
    }
    else
     {
        if (recogniser.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
            NSLog(@"continue...");
            CGPoint pt=[recogniser locationInView:self.view];

            float dis=[recogniser distanceBetweenPoints:center with:pt];

            if (dis<radius) 
            {
                if (recogniser.rotation>=0) 
                {
                    NSLog(@"Rotation value: +ve: %f",recogniser.rotation);
                    toStart = YES;
                    toAngle =fromAngle+(rotationMultiplier*3.14);         
                    recogniser.rotation = 0; 
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Rotation value: -ve: %f",recogniser.rotation);
                    toStart = YES;
                    toAngle=fromAngle-(rotationMultiplier*3.14);              
                    recogniser.rotation = 0;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

Here rotate method is calling multiple times.
```

Comment: Hello Prince, thanks for the quick reply but I am not trying to achieve animating an image multiple times. Below is what I am trying to do, I have an array of UIView (basically tiles), I want to arrange it on my screen and I want to do that with an animation ie 2nd view appear after the first, 3rd after second and so on, rather than putting all of them in the screen at one shot. Do try running my code, you will know what I am trying to achieve.